# Beginner to OOP and Java: is my approach correct?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

New to Java and OOP and trying to figure out ArrayList, and Objects in ArrayList. The following program works but I cannot help but get the niggling feeling I am not doing things (or thinking about things) in the right way. To me it seems clunky the way I am doing things and if I was to say add another 100 dogs how would I get the data in without having to have multiple lines of setters? I am keen on starting out correctly and getting in good habits before I move on.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Dogprint2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dog doggy = new Dog();
        doggy.setbreed("Alsation");
        doggy.setsize(5);

        ArrayList<Dog> dog2 = new ArrayList<Dog>();

        dog2.add(doggy);

        for (Dog d : dog2) {
            System.out.println(d.getsize());
            System.out.println(d.getbreed());
            if (d.getsize() == 5) {
                d.bark();
            }
        }       
    }
}
class Dog {
    private int size;
    private String breed;

    public void setbreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
    public void setsize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public int getsize() {
        return size;
    }
    public String getbreed() {
        return breed;
    }
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Bark!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just have added a constructor `public Dog (String breed, int size) {...}` and then create a new object `Dog dog = new Dog("Corgi",2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start of by splitting this into two seperate .java files, for example Dogprint2.java and Dog.java

Dogprint2.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Dogprint2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dog doggy = new Dog();
        doggy.setbreed("Alsation");
        doggy.setsize(5);

        ArrayList<Dog> dog2 = new ArrayList<Dog>();

        dog2.add(doggy);

        for (Dog d : dog2) {
            System.out.println(d.getsize());
            System.out.println(d.getbreed());
            if (d.getsize() == 5) {
                d.bark();
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

and Dog.java

```
class Dog {
    private int size;
    private String breed;

    public Dog(){
    }

    public Dog(String breed, int size){
        this.breed = breed;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setbreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
    public void setsize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public int getsize() {
        return size;
    }
    public String getbreed() {
        return breed;
    }
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Bark!");
    }
}
```

And as you can see I added two methods in the Dog class called constructors.
The first one, 'public Dog()' creates a new dog with no size or breed.

The second one on the other hand, 'public Dog(String breed, int size)' will create a new dog with the given paramaters.
Constructors is something you would like to have in your classes in order to create new instances of that given object/class.

Using this you will be able to avoid all the setters you use, asuming you know the breed and size of the dog when you create it. If you would like to create say 100 dogs and they all have the same breed and size then you can put this in a for loop in your main method. If they don't have the same breed and size you would like to either read them from a file or from the standard input. Creating 100 different dogs in the main method would otherwise end up being 100 lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you can include a constructor for initialize the class. You can use the method set for future modifications for object value. The constructor is like: public SameNameLikeClass(type parameter1, ..., type paramenter n){ variables}. And the initialization will be like new Dog(breedValue, sizeValue).

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in a for loop like:

```
for (int i =0; i<100; i++) {
    Dog doggy = new Dog();
    doggy.setbreed("Alsation");//name you define in an array/list and can keep on repeating like array[i%array.length]
    doggy.setsize(5);//numbers can be random?
    dog2.add(doggy);
}
```